# File not updating after reading and writing

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to read and write to a file.
My file contains just one line that has a value.
[image]

and this is my code where I am trying to calculate a mean value and write it in the file instead of the first one, but the file keeps containing `37`.

```
long int moy;
std::string line;
std::fstream file;
long int x = 35 + ( std::rand() % ( 37 - 35 + 1 ) );
file.open ("C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4/src/inet/applications/udpapp/B1.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
std::getline(file, line);
std::cout<<line<<endl;
moy=(x+stoi(line))/2;
file<<moy<<endl;
file.close();
```

The x variable contains different value every time, I also tried to write a string directly: `file<<"test"<<endl;` but still not updating.

Comment: At least for the code you show you did not seed the random number generator 1 time. This may or may not be the problem as this code is not a [mcve]

Comment: If you do seed the random number generator correctly in `int main()` before executing the code that is in the question then maybe you are using a very old version of MinGW that had a bug in the random number generation.

Comment: In either case you probably got downvoted because you did not attempt to debug your code and show evidence of your debugging session in your question about the result of your debugging effort like what was the value of `x` after `long int x = 35 + ( std::rand() % ( 37 - 35 + 1 ) );`  is that always the same? Is the problem with the file at all? If you stepped through the code line by line in a debugger looking at the variables at each step you should know what is going on.

Comment: the random number is diffrent every time, so I am sure that the number x is changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to close the file before reopening it for writing.

```
file.open ("C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4/src/inet/applications/udpapp/B1.txt", std::ios::in);
std::getline(file, line);
file.close();
std::cout<<line<<endl;
moy=(x+stoi(line))/2;
file.open ("C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4/src/inet/applications/udpapp/B1.txt", std::ios::out);
file<<moy<<endl;
file.close();
```

If you don't want to do that then you need to clear any error, and then reposition the file to the beginning.

```
file.clear(); // clear any error
file.seekp(0); // position file at beginning
```

The problem with this method is that it will not replace existing content. If your new line is shorter than the old line then the trailing characters of the old line will remain.